# MySQL: find specific word from SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE CONCAT(name) LIKE '% irfan %';

Table
Irfan Khan
Irfan Chisti
Irfan
Irfan Bhatti
```

I want the result like in sorting

**Output:**

```
Irfan
Irfan Bhatti
Irfan Chisti
Irfan Khan
```

Comment: Please put more effort into asking a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It's not clear what (if anything) you tried to solve the problem yourself. It's also not clear, what the question is exactly. If it's just about sorting a database query result, then: did you google that? That's a basic explained in pretty much every single mysql tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what your table and columns exactly look like and what purpose the "concat" in your example should have. Generally, you can sort using the keyword "ORDER BY", so in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%irfan%' ORDER BY name
```

In case the whole name is in one column, this will work correctly. Otherwise, it might be required to concat first name and last name or similar. If you need further information, please add more details to your question.